# strange issue in css in react component

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, sass

I have one `div` component in react. it is used to display `serchable dropdown` in react.

[image]

if there is `extension` in the browser it is coming over the component. like you can see `icon` above the component. when I inspected this component it is coming like below.one `image` is getting inserted inside the `div`.

[image]

when I am testing in another `browser` where , there is `no extension` it is not coming like that. it is proper.

[image]

how can I prevent my `div` tag to insert image automatically?

this icon keeps moving when I type the `text`.

[image]

Comment: May be the base 64 image is not supported in the browser

Comment: or check whether the image has cors problem... Check in network tab

Comment: thank you. anything I can do to prevent? because this issue is not cming in other component or elements

Comment: I recommend you to not use base 64 images just try to use https:// images

Comment: and also consider checking that in the second image you have attached there is no style attribute... Which also could cause the problem

Comment: can you tell me what to do for that?

Comment: May be you are not running the latest file in another browser...

Answer (score 0):

This is the icon that comes from `LastPass` extension.

And icon apears on input tag (in your case, react-select has input tag in value container)

If you want to hide from your site for all users, you can add following CSS style

```
img[id^=__lpform_][id$=_icon]{
  display: none;
}
```

If you want to remove the node from html, you can add following JS snippet.

```
    var lastPassInterval;

    lastPassInterval=setInterval(()=>{
       document.querySelectorAll("[id^=__lpform_] [id$=_icon]")
       .forEach(el=>{ el.remove(); clearInterval(lastPassInterval)})
    },500)
```

Above code snippet will find all these img tags with matching IDs, and remove it from html.

***Another way***

In react-select on Input Component you need to pass `data-lpignore="true"`, It will prevent LastPass from displaying icons in input. Check below answer for more info.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/53089923/14614051